# Reduce[] results filtering

Tags: equation-solving

I just started using mathematica at school, so this is a newbie question.
From a previous question i managed to get this:

```
ClearAll[x];
Reduce[505 == 500 + Mod[Mod[x, 66], 9], x, Integers]
(* Element[C[1], Integers] && (x == 5 + 66*C[1] || x == 14 + 66*C[1] || 
   x == 23 + 66*C[1] || x == 32 + 66*C[1] || x == 41 + 66*C[1] || 
   x == 50 + 66*C[1] || x == 59 + 66*C[1]) *)
```

I know that the answer that i am looking for is x=5,000
But if i give this command:

```
 FindInstance[
 C[1] ∈ 
   Integers && (x == 5 + 66 C[1] || x == 14 + 66 C[1] || 
    x == 23 + 66 C[1] || x == 32 + 66 C[1] || x == 41 + 66 C[1] || 
    x == 50 + 66 C[1] || x == 59 + 66 C[1]), {x}, 10]
```

i get the results:

```
{{x -> 28157}, {x -> -27112}, {x -> 18353}, {x -> -8275}, {x -> 
   3644}, {x -> 4613}, {x -> 32957}, {x -> -24415}, {x -> -21004}, {x -> 2342}}
```

Where is my x=5000 solution?
How can i tell mathematica to give me only the solutions for lets say x>0 && x<10000 ?
Is this possible?

Comment: `FindInstance[
 C[1] \[Element] 
   Integers && (x == 5 + 66 C[1] || x == 14 + 66 C[1] || 
    x == 23 + 66 C[1] || x == 32 + 66 C[1] || x == 41 + 66 C[1] || 
    x == 50 + 66 C[1] || x == 59 + 66 C[1]) && 4000 < x < 6000, {x, 
  C[1]}]`?

Comment: FindInstance[ C[1] \[Element]   Integers && (x == 5 + 66 C[1] || x == 14 + 66 C[1] ||    x == 23 + 66 C[1] || x == 32 + 66 C[1] || x == 41 + 66 C[1] ||   x == 50 + 66 C[1] || x == 59 + 66 C[1]) && 0 < x < 6000, {x, 
  C[1]}, 20]  Why is not showing my 5000 solution!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in results in a certain range, you can try using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) instead, and adding the condition to the expression, like so:

```
ClearAll[sol, vals, x];
sol = Solve[505 == 500 + Mod[Mod[x, 66], 9] && 0 < x < 10000, x, Integers];
```

I'm suppressing output because there's a lot of it!

```
Length@sol
(* 1061 *)
```

Note that `Solve` returns solutions as rules. Here are the first five:

```
Take[sol, 5]
(* {{x -> 5}, {x -> 14}, {x -> 23}, {x -> 32}, {x -> 41}} *)
```

We can get the list of values using `ReplaceAll`:

```
vals = x /. sol;
Take[vals, 5]
(* {5, 14, 23, 32, 41} *)
```

We can check to make sure that $ 5000 $ is indeed a solution:

```
MemberQ[vals, 5000]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Pillsy, thanks...Again!!!